# Trying to make SCons Ada Builder work with VariantDir

Tags: builder, ada, scons, build-system

I'm struggling with the last pieces of logic to make our Ada builder work as expectedly with variantdir. The problem is caused by the fact that the inflexible tools `gnatbind` and `gnatlink` doesn't allow the binder files to be placed in a directory other than the current one. This leaves me with two options:

- Let gnatbind write the the binder files to topdir and then let gnatlink pick it from there. This may however cause race conditions if we want to allow simulatenous builds for different architectures and compiler versions which we want.
- Modify the calls to gnatbind and gnatlink to temporarily go down to the build directory, in our case `build/$ARCH/src-path`. I successfully fixed the `gnatbind` step as this is explicitly called using a `env.Execute` from within the Ada builder. To try to fix the linking step I've modified the Program env using

  env["LINKCOM"] = SCons.Action.Action(ada_linkcom)

where `ada_linkcom` is defined as

```
def ada_linkcom(source, target,env ):
    ....
    return ret
```

where `ret` is a string describing what should be done in the shell. I need this to be a function it contains a bit complicated logic to convert paths from being relative to top-level to just containing their basenames.

This however fails with an error in `scons-2.3.1/SCons/Executor.py` on line 347 in function `do_execute`. Isn't `env["LINKCOM"]` allowed to be a function with ada_linkcom's signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not. You seem to think that 'env["LINKCOM"]' is what actually calls/executes the final build command, and that's not quite correct. Instead, environment variables like LINKCOM get expanded by the Executor/Builder for each specified Action, and are then executed.

You can have Python functions as Actions, and also use a so-called "generator" to create your Action strings on-the-fly. But you have to assign this Action to a Builder, and can't set it as an environment variable directly.

Please also have a look at the UserGuide ( http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html ), especially section 18.4 "Builders That Execute Python Functions". Our basic guide for writing Builders and Tools might also prove to be helpful: http://www.scons.org/wiki/ToolsForFools

Comment: So in this case I have to override or create a new Program builder then?

Comment: Yes, pretty much so. I'd recommend to name your Builder differently, so you can have both at the same time within the same Environment. As long as your build step is similar to an already existing Builder (like compiling simple C/CXX files with Program) the idea is to "parameterize" the Builder via environment variables like "$CC". But in your case the way things work is just too special...so it's probably better to also make this apparent to users by giving the Builder a different name.